# HOW TO PREVENT USER FROM DELETING INDEX IN ELASTICSEARCH

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

i have created one role suppose X role in kibana which restricts user from deleting any index as i was giving create,read and write privilege so no user with X role can delete any of the index.
but , users are able to delete indexes with _delete_by_query API. How can i restrict users from deleting any of the index as we have critical data in it !

Comment: What privileges does the role have? Delete an index and delete documents using `delete_by_query` are different things. If your user has the `write` privilege to the index, then it will be able to delete documents. You should give just the `read` privilege in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The `_delete_by_query` API doesn't delete the index, but the documents present in that index.

The `write` privilege allows to create new documents but also to delete some.